# Preexisting Serializer to [FromQuery] format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to consume an **ASP.NET Core Web API** method that includes `[FromQuery]` parameters.

Since the format is somewhat unusual, I figured there would exist a library function that would take a complex type and generate the query string formatted text - however, I can't find one.

IOW, given a controller method defined like this:

```
[HttpGet("testing")]
public bool Testing([FromQuery]X x)
{
    return (x?.Ys[1]?.Zs[1]?.Bs[3] == 3 && x?.Ys[1]?.Zs[0]?.A == 4);
}
```

And an X defined like this:

```
public class X
{
    public Y[] Ys { get; set; }
}
public class Y
{
    public Z[] Zs { get; set; }
}
public class Z
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int[] Bs { get; set; }
}
```

First of all, what's an example of what ASP.NET [FromQuery] is expecting to encounter in the query string in order to return true?

Secondly, is there a function somewhere that can serialize an object appropriately into whatever ASP.NET is expecting, or do I need to write one?

Comment: I believe you'd need to write serializer by your yourself. Do you need serializer in `C#` or `JS`?

Comment: @Alexander C# - I figure I'll have to write one myself, but it feels like the kind of thing that should be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following "serializer"

```
public class QueryStringSerializer
{
    private static bool IsPrimitive(object obj)
    {
        return obj.GetType().IsPrimitive || obj is string || obj is Guid;
    }

    private static bool IsEnumerable(object obj)
    {
        return obj is IEnumerable && !IsPrimitive(obj);
    }

    private static bool IsComplex(object obj)
    {
        return !(obj is IEnumerable) && !IsPrimitive(obj);
    }

    private static StringBuilder ToQueryStringInternal(object obj, string prop = null)
    {
        StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();

        //skip null values
        if (obj == null)
            return queryString;

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (IsEnumerable(obj))
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (object item in obj as IEnumerable)
            {
                string query = ToQueryStringInternal(item, $"{prop}[{i}]").ToString();
                queryString.Append(query);
                i++;
            }
        }
        else if (IsComplex(obj))
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                string propName = property.Name;
                object value = property.GetValue(obj);

                string name = prop == null ? propName : $"{prop}.{propName}";

                string query = ToQueryStringInternal(value, name).ToString();
                queryString.Append(query);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToString(obj));
            queryString.Append($"{prop}={encoded}&");
        }

        return queryString;
    }

    public static string ToQueryString(object obj, string propertyName = null)
    {
        StringBuilder queryString = ToQueryStringInternal(obj, propertyName);
        queryString.Length--;
        return queryString.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var x = new X
{
    Ys = new Y[] {
        new Y {
            Zs = new Z[] { new Z { } }
        },
        new Y {
            Zs = new Z[] {
                new Z { },
                new Z {
                    A = 1,
                    Bs = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

string query = QueryStringSerializer.ToQueryString(x);
```

Result

```
Ys[0].Zs[0].A=0&Ys[1].Zs[0].A=0&Ys[1].Zs[1].A=1&Ys[1].Zs[1].Bs[0]=0&Ys[1].Zs[1].Bs[1]=1&Ys[1].Zs[1].Bs[2]=2&Ys[1].Zs[1].Bs[3]=3
```

**Caution**

The serializer may still contain various bags. Also, do not create array with "gaps" such as

```
var q = new X[] {
    new X { },
    null, //a gap
    new X { }
};
```

The result will be technically correct but `ASP.NET` model binder will bind only the first element properly.